# How do I return a reference in rust, that is automatically dereferenced

Tags: rust, indexing, struct, reference, traits

Let's say I have the struct:

```rust
struct Vector {
    data: [f32; 2]
}
```

Implementing the Index trait is easy:

```rust
impl IndexMut<usize> for Vector {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        &mut self.data[index]
    }
}
```

I also have this implementation:

```
impl Vector {
    fn x(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.data[0]
    }
    fn y....
}
```

Technically I can do it, but each time I want to actually set the value of x() I need to dereference it: `*v.x() = 7` works, but I would like `v.x() = 7` to also work.

When I try to second one I get the error: `consider dereferencing here to assign to the mutably borrowed value: '*'`, which I guess makes sense, but it's weird that it happens, since IndexMut returns the same mutable reference that my x() function returns.

So my question is: Why does the IndexMut trait work to just do `v[0] = 7`, but my function needs to be dereferenced before using the value, and how (if even possible) should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v[0] = 7` doesn't need dereferencing because `v[0]` is syntax sugar for `*v.index(0)` or `*v.index_mut(0)` depending on how it's used<sup>*</sup>, that is the compiler automatically inserts the dereference wherever you use the indexing syntax, this is presumably done so indexing works the same as in other languages and is a little easier to use.

As far as I know there is no way to get the same behaviour for your own method.

---

<sub>*As you can see from the docs on [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) and [`IndexMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html)</sub>

Comment: This is sad. I guess I will have to just have different structs for vec2, vec3, and vec4 instead of just making a generic for all of them. At least that's the only way I can think of doing it, but that's a different question entirely, unrelated to this one.